# Does "config add --overwrite" reset any cache state, is it bad to do repeatedly?

Tags: jfrog-cli

A project I'm working on uses `jf rt download ...` a dozen times or so preceding our automated builds.

A recent build script change now has us doing `jf config add Key --overwrite ...` then `jf config use Key` before every `jf rt download ...` where it used to do the `jf config add` only once at the beginning.

Ignoring whether `jf config use` is redundant to use repeatedly for now, does it make a difference that our scripts do `jf config add` every time now too? Does it reset state perhaps to make anything slower and should this practice be avoided, or does it not matter?

Then also, does it actually matter that `jf config use` is done before every `jf rt download` too?

Answer (score 0):

The `jf config add` command configures a new JFrog instance locally in your machine. If username and password are provided, it sends one GET request to `/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword`, to store an encrypted password. Therefore the overhead of running it twice is as a single GET request to Artifactory.

The `--overwrite` flag allows overriding existing server configuration. This flag was added for convenience because the following commands are equal:

```
jf config add <existed-server-id> --overwrite
```

```
jf config edit <existed-server-id>
```

Another option is to run the download command with the server details flags:

```
jf rt download <source> <target> --url https://acme.jfrog.io --user <username> --password <password>
```

> Does it make a difference that our scripts do jf config add every time now too?

The idea behind the `jf config add` command is to prevent providing the server details multiple times. You can run it once before all followed `jf` commands.

> Does it reset state perhaps to make anything slower and should this practice be avoided, or does it not matter

It does not reset any state.

> does it actually matter that jf config use is done before every jf rt download too

It is enough to run it once in the beginning of the script, although the overhead is negligible.